# Why doesn't "this.function" work in a modal popup but $scope does?

Tags: angularjs

In the modal controller I was trying to use 
this.cancel = function () ....  but the function never got called.
I had to change it to $scope.cancel .... for it to work and I'm trying to understand why that is.

this."whatever" does work in the main controller

Code snippet :

```
function MainController($uibModal) {
   //this works 
   this.popup = function () {
         $uibModal.open({
             controller: 'PopupCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'myctrl.html'     
    });
};
}

function PopupController($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

  //"this.cancel" does not work, need to use $scope
 $scope.cancel = function (){
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
 };
 //"this" wont work
  this.ok = function (){
     $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  };
}
```

I've created a Plunker to show the example

http://plnkr.co/edit/nMBe6SqXzicxkHNT5JdT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your plunker. [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/4KdbgcEkHWkMNVmh7Z8q?p=preview) is my version

```
    this.popup = function () {
         $uibModal.open({
            controller: 'PopupCtrl as popupctrl',
            templateUrl: 'myctrl.html'

    });
```

The key here is the syntax **"PopupCtrl as popupctrl"**

popupctrl is the reference to your modal controller. In the view I did this:

```
ng-click="popupctrl.ok()"
```

Note that I used that "reference".

Comment: Great!  Thanks for your help